# Question Overflowing into tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

In the process of naval gazing, I came across this question: [What resources exist for database performance tuning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761204/what-resources-exist-for-database-performance-tuning).  If you scroll down to the bottom of the question the tags are flowing into the last 3 items of the list.  I'm assuming that this is because questions have a fixed height?

Comment: Have a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's yet another manifestation of this problem:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post

I fixed the question.